Guidance on development of FM radio
I am in the process of learning all about FM/AM and already have managed to make my own working transmitter. All these are some starting steps in order to make my own FM radio. Regarding that, I would like to ask you what direction do you think is best.

Make both my own RF to IF mixer, and demodulator
Use some ICs for some steps of the process
Take a ready IC like TEA5767, and turn the whole hardware problem into a coding one

Basically, my question boils down to, are out of the box ICs like TD7000 and TEA5767, good enough to make a commercial grade radio, or would I have better luck just making the circuit from scratch (maybe with some complementary ICs)?

Yes, they are good enough – that's why the exist. If not companies building commercial radios, who would buy them? Designing a chip is so expensive, you simply can't do it just for a couple thousand hobbyists.

Also note that the TDA7000 is already quite ancient, and very likely (actually, certainly) not in production anymore, so all you can buy are probably overstock / untested and mislabeled things. The TEA5767 is already very old, too, and probably not being produced anymore, either. Strange choices! Look at major distributor's RF receiver IC categories and filter for "Active" (not: "obsolete" or "not recommended for new designs"), and for "In Stock", and of course for "protocol/standard=FM" and you'll get an idea of what exists in the modern era.

@MarcusMüller Thanks a lot for the advice. I settled on Si4704/05-D60, for my FM receiver, and it seems exactly what I need. I wish you the best

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
